# Load Table based on value selected in drop down

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I hava a jsp which contains a dropdown. Based on the value selected in the dropdown I need to populate a table on the same jsp with values.

**The JSP:**

```
  <h3>Please select Platform:</h3>
  <select id="platforms" name="platforms">
   <option value=""></option>
   <%
    GetPathFromExcel getpathfromexcel=new GetPathFromExcel();
                        Set<String> platforms = new HashSet<String>();
                        platforms= getpathfromexcel.getPlatformColumn();
                        for (String s : platforms){
   %>
   <option value="<%=s%>"><%=s%></option>
   <%
    }
   %>
  </select>
  <h3>Please select Graph:</h3>
  <form name="form1">
   <div style="width: 300px; height: 500px; overflow: auto;">
    <table border="1" id="table">
     <thead>
      <th>Graph</th>
      <th><input id="selectAll" type="checkbox" title="Select All"
       onClick="checkall(this)"></th>
     </thead>

     <%
        Set<String> graphs = new HashSet<String>();
                            graphs=getpathfromexcel.getGraphs();
                            for(String g : graphs){
     %>
     <tr>
      <td><%=g%></td>
      <td><input name="select" type="checkbox" id=<%=g%>></td>
     </tr>
     <%
        }
     %>


    </table>
   </div>

   <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
  </form>
 </div>
```

Based on the value I select in the platforms dropdown, I need the graphs to be loaded:

```
graphs=getpathfromexcel.getGraphs();
```

I can obviously get the value of the platform selected by:

```
$("#platforms").change(function(){
        var platformSelected=$("#platforms").val();
    });
```

The code I have mentioned above will obviously not work since the embedded Java code will be run on the server-side while the Javascript bit is on the client-side. How can I get this to work?

Comment: In this case, client and server side play important role. You should pass platform to the server side (Java) in order for it to give response  based on platform changed. For e.g: graphs=getpathfromexcel.getGraphs(platformSelected);

Comment: I tried that but platformSelected is computed only after selecting a platform while the Java code to fetch the graphs runs on the server before that while loading the page